# How to install ATI Radeon 3650 driver on Windows 8 RTM, pre-release?

Tags: windows-8, ati-mobility-radeon

Windows 8 comes with an AMD/ATI driver, but it fails at openGL. (Well, and at 3D too.)
So I wanted to install an official AMD driver, but it's not that simple.

AMD dropped the support for 2xxx/3xxx/4xxx cards since 12.6.
12.4 is not released for Windows 8.

12.8 comes with WDDM1.2, but as the support for my card is dropped, I have no chance to get it work.
Any ideas?

Comment: The answer is you cannot.  You can wait until the community perhaps hacks the supported drivers, but until said time, you are out of luck.  My advice to you is don't upgrade to Windows 8 unless you are able to upgrade your graphics card.

Comment: @Ramhound - Well, I think I'll go and install Ubuntu. I need OpenGL fast, and I'm not patient enough to reinstall Windows 7 right now. Thank you. Post that as an answer, or should I delete my question?

Comment: I don't make a habit of postings answers.  I am tired of people downvoting my answers for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. AMD says you shouldn't use the "beta Windows" (which is RTM/gold.. but whatever).
You should upgrade because the 7xxx series is out and it's ubercool you know, you can view your pictures faster and stuff. Maybe they even draw the windows more blue. WHO KNOWS?

Unless the OEM will provide drivers, the old cards are dead on Windows 8. That's all.
Link: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8/T500-Drivers-for-Windows-8-Enterprise-x64/td-p/834657

(Ps.: I know these cards are not the latest ones... but I see no point in upgrading. In fact, this is not a desktop machine. You can't just buy a cheap new GPU and install it...)

Comment: Windows 8 has NOT been released.  Like I said I am sure the community will hack the current drivers to support your card.  You just have to wait until the community upgrades to Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

After two months of playing with openGL apps in linux.. I managed to instal the driver located at http://www2.ati.com/drivers/legacy/amd_catalyst_12.6_legacy_win8.exe

The driver installed without hacks. Double click the executable, next next next, and it works. I was surprised.

My system is a studio 1555 with mobility HD 4570. I run windows 8 x64. OpenGL works according to blender, openCL works according to GPU-z. Even CCC is functioning correctly.